# Curl POST request to grails controller

Tags: curl, grails

Using the following curl request to post json data to grails controller but getting empty json.Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong in the curl request

curl -v -g -k -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -X POST -d '{"id":1,"orderDateTime":"07/10/2020","orderTypeId":1}' https://localhost:8444/orderapp/placeOrder

grails Controller code

```
def saveOrder() {
        def m=[:]
        def orderJson = request.JSON
        println "JSON data.......${orderJson}"

        def orderInstance = new Order()
        orderInstance.properties = orderJson
        m.id = orderInstance.id
        render m as JSON
}
```

Comment: What's the status of the response? Are there errors in the log?

Comment: @cfrick here is the response  HTTP/1.1 200
< X-Application-Context: application:development:8444
< Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Thu, 16 Jul 2020 17:32:40 GMT
<
{"id":null}* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact. Only issue is getting empty json

Comment: Plese [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62939624/edit) the question